# External HTTPS REST call with Basic Auth isn't working in Mule

Tags: rest, https, mule, basic-authentication

I'm trying to make an external HTTPS call in Mule with Basic Authentication. Below is an extract of my application:

```
<http:request-config name="HTTPS_Request_Configuration" protocol="HTTPS" doc:name="HTTP Request Configuration">
    <http:basic-authentication username="username" password="password"/>
    <tls:context>
        <tls:key-store type="jks" path="keystore.jks" alias="mule" keyPassword="password" password="password"/>
    </tls:context>
</http:request-config>

<flow name="get:/clients/{clientId}:api-config">
    <logger message="#['Retrieving client with ID: ' + flowVars['clientId']]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
    <http:request config-ref="HTTPS_Request_Configuration" path="/api/clients/{clientId}" method="GET" host="host.com" port="443" doc:name="HTTP">
        <http:request-builder>
            <http:uri-param paramName="clientId" value="#[flowVars['clientId']]"/>
        </http:request-builder>
        <http:success-status-code-validator values="0..599"/>
    </http:request>
    <logger message="#[payload]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
</flow>
```

Using the above configurations I'm consistnetly getting 401 responses from the API I'm trying to call. Making calls via Postman with the exact same details work fine.

I have imported the certificate of the target host into my keystore. I'm using Mule version 3.7.3.

Any thoughts around what mightbe missing / what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `preemptive="true"` to the `http:basic-authentication` element:

```
<http:basic-authentication username="username"
                           password="password"
                           preemptive="true"  />
```